# extract all the servers by parsing json response using python?

Tags: python, json, http

I have a service urlA that if I call gives me below json response which has list of servers in it keyed by datacenter. In future, I can have more keys and more servers for each keys.

```
{
    "abc": ["goldy11.abc.host.com", "goldy12.abc.host.com"],
    "pqr": ["goldy21.pqr.host.com", "goldy22.pqr.host.com"],
    "def": ["goldy31.def.host.com", "goldy32.def.host.com"],
    "jhk": ["goldy41.jhk.host.com", "goldy42.jhk.host.com"]
}
```

Similarly I have another service urlB which gives similar response but different set of servers:

```
{
    "abc": ["goldy81.abc.host.com", "goldy82.abc.host.com"],
    "pqr": ["goldy91.pqr.host.com", "goldy92.pqr.host.com"],
    "def": ["goldy71.def.host.com", "goldy72.def.host.com"],
    "jhk": ["goldy51.jhk.host.com", "goldy52.jhk.host.com"]
}
```

I want to extract all the server names from the above json response from both the url's which will be like this:

```
goldy11.abc.host.com
goldy12.abc.host.com
goldy21.pqr.host.com
goldy22.pqr.host.com
goldy31.def.host.com
goldy32.def.host.com
goldy41.jhk.host.com
goldy42.jhk.host.com
goldy81.abc.host.com
goldy82.abc.host.com
goldy91.pqr.host.com
goldy92.pqr.host.com
goldy71.def.host.com
goldy72.def.host.com
goldy51.jhk.host.com
goldy52.jhk.host.com
```

So I started off like this but I am kinda confuse on how to extract all the servers by parsing json response from both the service url without specifying any key in hardcoded way?

```
import json
import requests

responsea = requests.get("service-url-a")
responseb = requests.get("service-url-b")
json_data_a = json.loads(responsea.text)
json_data_b = json.loads(responseb.text)
# how can I combine both json_data_a and json_data_b response in the hosts list
hosts = [value for value_set in json_data_a.values() for value in value_set]
print hosts
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to flatten your array. With something like the following:

`hosts = [value for value_set in json_data.values() for value in value_set]`

This will give you a list of all the hosts. You can then proceed with the rest of your task from there.

Comment: got it. I have two urls for which I need to call and parse their json respone. can I combine everything in one hosts variable? updated my question for more clarity.

Comment: You should be able to simply add the lists together via `master_list = hosts_a + hosts_b`

Comment: got it. And this hosts variable is a list right in python?

Comment: Or instead of j_a and j_b, just  `data = json.loads([a response]...` followed by  `data.update(json.loads([b response])...`

Comment: @flash yes hosts is a list.

Comment: @Wyrmwood are you sure it works? I tried but it's only showing servers for b response. `import json
import requests

responsea = requests.get("service-url-a")
responseb = requests.get("service-url-b")
json_data = json.loads(responsea.text)
json_data.update(json.loads(responseb.text))
hosts = [value for value_set in json_data.values() for value in value_set]
print hosts`

Comment: No. You're keys are the same so the update will overwrite them.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> import json
>>> a = """{
...     "abc": ["goldy11.abc.host.com", "goldy12.abc.host.com"],
...     "pqr": ["goldy21.pqr.host.com", "goldy22.pqr.host.com"],
...     "def": ["goldy31.def.host.com", "goldy32.def.host.com"],
...     "jhk": ["goldy41.jhk.host.com", "goldy42.jhk.host.com"]
... }"""

>>> b = """{
...     "abc": ["goldy81.abc.host.com", "goldy82.abc.host.com"],
...     "pqr": ["goldy91.pqr.host.com", "goldy92.pqr.host.com"],
...     "def": ["goldy71.def.host.com", "goldy72.def.host.com"],
...     "jhk": ["goldy51.jhk.host.com", "goldy52.jhk.host.com"]
... }"""
>>> data_a = json.loads(a)
>>> data_b = json.loads(b)
>>> print(json.dumps([value for values in list(data_a.values()) + list(data_b.values()) for value in values], indent=True))
[
 "goldy21.pqr.host.com",
 "goldy22.pqr.host.com",
 "goldy11.abc.host.com",
 "goldy12.abc.host.com",
 "goldy41.jhk.host.com",
 "goldy42.jhk.host.com",
 "goldy31.def.host.com",
 "goldy32.def.host.com",
 "goldy91.pqr.host.com",
 "goldy92.pqr.host.com",
 "goldy81.abc.host.com",
 "goldy82.abc.host.com",
 "goldy51.jhk.host.com",
 "goldy52.jhk.host.com",
 "goldy71.def.host.com",
 "goldy72.def.host.com"
]
```